# Calling a function in wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm writing a basic wordpress widget for my theme. I need to call my function inside the function widget. My function is located just outside the widget For example:

```
function my_function( $arg ) {
    ...
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    my_function($arg);
}
```

and it will give me error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function my_function() in...
```

However if i place my_function inside the widget function, then it works. For example:

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    function my_function( $arg ) {
        ...
    }

    my_function($arg);
}
```

I want to know why this would not work if it is placed outside the widget function? Thanks.

Comment: It the `widget` function in a class?

Comment: in the first example is the `my_function` in the same class? if so how do you call is? `self::,my_function` or `$this->my_function`? And is it defined `public`, `static` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be in a PHP class (plugin class) when you declare your functions.

So try to modify your code like this :

```
function my_function( $arg ) {
    ...
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    $ClassName->my_function($arg);
}
```

I think it might be better then!
Let me know!

Comment: I'm surprised to see that you call this method not by using $this->my_function() but by $ClassName->my_function() which is unusual.